# Oracle Apex 5.1: About creating an empty input form like the input form when creating table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to create a form using oracle apex 5.1 like the image below. But I do not know how to create it. Could anyone direct me achieve this?

[image: Create Table Image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use **APEX_ITEM.TEXT** in your query:

```
select  empno, 
    APEX_ITEM.TEXT(25,ename) ename,
    job, mgr, hiredate from emp;
```

You have to click on column (*ename*) in Columns section of your report and set Escape special character to **No**. 
If you use Interactive report you can put **HTML Expression** for every column like:

```
 <input type="text" value="#JOB#">
```

To show data from column in input just set value to be **#NAME_OF_COLUMN#**.
For empty input just add column in query:`APEX_ITEM.TEXT(25,'') text_input` or if you prefer second aproach add empty column and set HTML expression.

`select  empno, ename,'' as text, job, mgr, hiredate from emp;`

 Here is APEX_ITEM.TEXT function from Oracle Apex doc.

```
APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
p_idx         IN    NUMBER,
p_value       IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_size        IN    NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
p_maxlength   IN    NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
p_attributes  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_item_id     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_item_label  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Items` can be created in an `HTML Region` to create a form. You will then need to create `Processes` to perform the action(s) required when submitting the form.
The documentation explains it step by step : https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/HTMDB/app_forms004.htm#HTMDB30063

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I am sorry I did not understand from the link how to make a table like the image. For now I have created a pl/sql dynamic content where I have made an html table with two columns where each cell's input type is 'text'. And also added a button to dynamically add rows. But now stuck with how to identify each row values for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Integrated Grid feature that replaced the "old" tabular form:

See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/about-making-grids-editable.htm#HTMDB-GUID-0A317D17-5B12-4F4A-B5C8-68807DB5A4C1