# Create an insert values table as the added image

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to replicate an insert values table as the following:

[image]

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: If you use APEX 4.x - it is "tabular form", if APEX 5.x - "Interactive Grid". If these options doesn't fit for you needs, please provide more information.

Comment: What I really need is to carry out the same tabular form. I mean, the query which is behind the tabular form is select nom_table, nom_column, num_column from column. When i have done the previous done, the tabular form, shows me all the record from the table but I also want to carry out a tabular form to insert records. Is it possible to generate a tabular form like the image I have added but only to insert values?

Comment: If you have already a tabular form generated by APEX, it has a "Add row" button. You can click it to add a row, then it will be inserted. If you want to add rows automatically, you can simulate clicks on button in javascript.

Comment: Hi Dmitry! Thanks for your help. But the problem is that I only want the tabular form to insert records into a table from the data base. The idea is to create a tabular form as the one that can be shown in the above image. I mean, the example has a text field to create the table and inside the tabular form you have only empty rows to insert records into that table. That is what I really need!

Comment: Dmitry! Finally I have got the result I was following. I took the steps explained in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491263/oracle-apex-5-1-about-creating-an-empty-input-form-like-the-input-form-when-cre. Thanks you again!